# Xcode Instruments Attach to process

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

I have problem with Instruments in XCode.

I need to do so, because when you download a lot of operations and my computer can not handle and Instruments hang.

I need run application. As usual, and then connect to an already running tools. I'm trying to do so
[image]

But it's don't work. Instruments show not information about my running app

Thank you

Comment: Yes, I solved. You need select the name of the process which has a similar name, the name of your application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need select the name of the process which has a similar name, the name of your application

Answer (score 3):

**For others with a newer version of Instruments:**

To me the only way to attach to a process without starting it was to select **All Processes** and start profiling. Then unfold the data for your app afterwatch.